# Iframe doesn't show onload, but it does after manual reload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe

I'm using an Asp.net/C# environment and Visual Studio 2013 to create a web application.

I have a page (aspx) with only a single iframe in it, and a javascript method that uses jquery to put html into that frame.

```cs
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="MainSectionContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainSectionContentPlaceHolder">
    <section runat="server" id="FrameSection" clientidmode="Static">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FrameSectionContentPlaceHolder" />
        <iframe id="FrameContentFrame" name="FrameContentFrame" src="about:blank" seamless="seamless" onload=" loadFrameContent(); "></iframe>
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function loadFrameContent() {
            jQuery('#FrameContentFrame').contents().find('html').html('<%= FrameContent %>'); //FrameContent is a c# property which holds a syntactically correct html string
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

In my code behind I fetch a long string from a server and store it in the property FrameContent. This long strings is syntactically correct html.

The result should be:
onload, the javascript method runs. The iframe is populated with html and thus the html string is shown to the user.

but what really happens:
nothing is shown. a Javascript error occurs saying "the function loadFrameContent is undefined". But its clearly there if I view the page source in my web browser. If I right click on the blank page where the frame should be, and choose "reload frame" (Google Chrome), the frame does show the Html.

So: the Html string is correct. the frame is correct. the frame can display the html correctly. However, the frame cannot display the Html onload, it needs an additional manual reload to actually show anything! I checked the page source on my browser and the Javascript function IS present, and the FrameContent property is populated with the correct html string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, it looks like a timing issue. A blank iframe will be finished loading before your parent page, so it will call `loadFrameContent` before the parent page has finished parsing its dom (thus the method won't be registered). Get rid of the iframe onload and add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function loadFrameContent() {
        jQuery('#FrameContentFrame').contents().find('html').html('<%= FrameContent %>');     //FrameContent is a c# property which holds a syntactically correct html string
    }

    $(loadFrameContent);

    // Or if you're using an older version of jQuery
    //$(document).ready(loadFrameContent);
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I had to add additional parentheses: $(loadFrameContent()), but it worked. I was not aware of the onload timing issue. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work in FF and IE if the entire web application is inside an iframe inside microsoft CRM. But it does work on Chrome (always) and it does work on FF and IE if it's just viewed as a regular website (not built-in into CRM). Weird :(

Comment: MS CRM has it's own javascript nonsense that may be interfering with the calls. I'm not very familiar with it, but I've seen some of the code for it. Chrome isn't always as picky, but IE will bark at even the slightest hiccup. I would recommend putting some `console.log` statements into your code just to track its progress in IE or load up Firebug and attach it to Firefox to see what it's doing.

Comment: After some debugging, we made it work, but we don't really know what made it work. Our best guess is that we had two javascript functions with the same name. Our function was callled "loadFrame()", and it is proable this conflicted with a CRM javascript function because it's such a general name. to fix it, we prefixed all our functions with the company name.